# Nestjs set a variable on Service from interceptor

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I create an interceptor.
It checks if the user belongs to a channel with

```js
async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {

    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
    const channelId = ctx.getRequest()!.params

    //check if the user is the owner of the channel
    let checkChannel = await this.telegramService.checkChannel(ctx.getRequest()!.user, channelId.channelId)    
   
    return next.handle();
  }
```

In my Service I have:

```js
 async checkChannel(userId: string, channelId: string):Promise<IGateway> {
        currentChannel = await this.gatewayModel.findOne({ userId: userId, channelId: channelId })
        if (!currentChannel) {
            throw new HttpException(`Telegram channel Not Found`, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return currentChannel;
    }
```

If the channel exists, I'd like to set a variable like `currentChannel' in order to avoid to create another query to get the same result of the "check" query.

Now I put a variable
`let currentChannel;`
above the service, like:

```js
let currentChannel;

@Injectable()
export class TelegramService
```

It works, but I don't like. How can I set the variable from interceptor?

Comment: I guess you can use guards instead

Comment: hello, thanks for your anwer. The user authenticated already (JWT).  you suggest Guard anyway? If I switch to the Guard I have the same issue when I want to retrieve info from Db, I need to re-do the same query

Comment: Do you pass the request to the service at all?

Comment: Hello Jay, no I don't pass the request object.  Before the the interceptor I passed request.user._id. Probably your hint could be, put the `checkChannel` result into the request during interceptor and pass it to the service.

Thanks